# How to run a scala program in terminal?

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, terminal

I have created a .scala file in the Scala version of eclipse, it has a main and object. I want to somehow compile this possibly into a jar file, so I can run it from terminal?

any info will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the full process from the command line:

```
evan@vbox ~> cat test.scala
object test{
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("Hello!")
}
evan@vbox ~> scalac test.scala
evan@vbox ~> scala test
Hello!
```

However if you want to use Scala IDE to its full potential I would check out [this tutorial](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Tutorial).

Comment: Naturally you will need to make sure that both `scala` and `scalac` are in your path. How to do this depends on how you installed scala

Answer (score 2):

To create the JAR, follow this:

[Create a JAR from Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-33.htm)

Then you can run it with

```
java -cp /path/to/My.jar com.co.package.MyObj
```